# AIX apache rpm dependencies

Tags: software-installation, apache-httpd, rpm, aix

I am evaluating the [Crowd SSO](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) by Atlassian. Now to get apache to use CROWD for authentication, there is a [connector](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Integrating+Crowd+with+Apache#IntegratingCrowdwithApache-Step3.ChoosingtheCorrectApacheConnectorforyourOperatingSystem) available by the vendor.

### Problem

Unfortunately they do not provide anything for my OS (AIX). Instead they provide [source code with instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Installing+the+Crowd+Apache+Connector+on+Other+UNIX-Like+Systems). Now the example here uses `yum -y install autoconf automake gcc httpd-devel libcurl-devel libtool libxml2-devel mod_dav_svn subversion-devel` to download the required packages for which there is no alternate in AIX (AFAIK). So I went to AIX toolbox and got some packages. For the rest, I took [Mr Perzl's](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php) help. And while installing the `rpms` ended up getting dependency errors.

### Question

Do I go with

1. The solution given here [dependency hell](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=FAQs.FAQs#rpm-dependency-hell).
2. [IBM way](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.install/doc/insgdrf/HT_insgdrf_install_opensrc.htm)
3. Something else which Google and my limited exposure to AIX are not telling me.

I am not *nix expert, rather at basic user level. And any installations are actually done by the admins. So I need expert advice so as to get it right and efficiently if possible.

---

Appreciate if someone would like to retag this question for getting attention from the right people.

Comment: The IBM link displays briefly, then jumps to a "helpful" welcome page (gaaaaah, why do they do that!?).  I was able to interrupt the reload so I could read the page you linked to, but perhaps there would be a better way ...?  The actual content is at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/topic/com.ibm.aix.install/doc/insgdrf/HT_insgdrf_install_opensrc.htm but then you lose the context frame (no big loss IMHO).

Comment: The "dependency hell" link looks like the only real solution.  I don't see what the IBM documentation offers, apart from being less specific about your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Take the source, check on installation instructions, build and install. No need to install any alien RPM stuff. I don't remember offhand what package management AIX has, should perhaps check on how to build a native AIX package if you need it at several locations (Or just because. Or to contribute something back.).

Check for dependencies, you will have to find them and install them the same way, if they don't exist for AIX. Can be quite a chore.

OTOH, at least for Solaris there was a semi-official package repository with lots of third party stuff, like GCC and other GNU packages, and a random spattering of tools. Perhaps there is something like that for AIX too? Might ask specifically for external sources for packages for your version of AIX here.

Comment: perhaps I was not able to make this clear. Updated the question.

Comment: AIX apparently uses RPM too, only it's some ancient version which doesn't work with Yum, so you have to deal with dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

The [pkgsrc framework](http://pkgsrc.org/) could help you here (if you're willing to invest some time).  AIX support could be unstable though.

Comment: interesting.. trying to get this to work